# From given vector find max value and its index by reduction method in CUDA

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I am new to CUDA, for the vector to find max value and its index I use CUDA

here its my code:

```
#include < cuda.h >
#include < stdio.h >
#include < time.h >
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define tbp 256
#define nblocks 1
__global__ void kernel_max(int *a, int *d, int *index,int *idx)
{
    __shared__ int sdata[tbp]; //"static" shared memory

    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    sdata[tid] = a[i];
    index[tid] = i;
    __syncthreads();
    for(int s=tbp/2 ; s >= 1 ; s=s/2)
    {
        if(tid < s)
        {
            if(sdata[tid] < sdata[tid + s])
            {
                sdata[tid] = sdata[tid + s];
                index[tid] = index[tid+s];
             __syncthreads();
            }
            __syncthreads();
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if(tid == 0 ) 
    {
        d[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
        idx[blockIdx.x] = index[0];
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    const int N=tbp*nblocks;
    srand(time(NULL));

    int *a;
    a = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    int *d;
    d = (int*)malloc(nblocks * sizeof(int));
    int *index;
    index = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    int *idx;
    idx = (int*)malloc(nblocks * sizeof(int));

    int *dev_a, *dev_d, *dev_index,*dev_idx;

    cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_a, N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_d, nblocks*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_index, N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_idx, nblocks*sizeof(int));

    int mmm=0;
    int ddd=0;
    for( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand()% 100 + 5;
        index[i]=i;
        //printf("%d\n",a[i]);
        if(mmm<a[i]) 
        {
            mmm=a[i];
            ddd=i;  
        }
    }
    printf("");
    printf("");
    printf("");
    printf("");
    cudaMemcpy(dev_a , a, N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_index , index, N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel_max <<< nblocks,tbp >>>(dev_a,dev_d,dev_index,dev_idx);

    cudaMemcpy(d, dev_d, nblocks*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(index, dev_index, N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(idx, dev_idx, nblocks*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("cpu max= %d, gpu_max = %d ,cpu index: %d, gpu index: %d",mmm,d[0],ddd,idx[0]);
    printf("\n");

    if(ddd!=idx[0])
    {
        cout<<"index mismatch!damn!!"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"congratulations!!"<<endl;
    }
    /*
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        cout<<*(index+i)<<endl;
    */
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_d);
    cudaFree(dev_index);
    cudaFree(dev_idx);

    free(a);
    free(d);
    free(index);
    free(idx);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that for the tbp < 128 it can get correct result both in value and index
when increase to 256,512,1024, the result will sometimes go wrong.
Can anyone given a explanation for this situation?Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't your program keep running forever sometimes? Those `__syncthreads();` inside conditional statements look very dangerous to me because some threads might not even reach them.

Comment: The program doesn't keep running forever according to my test result, it just sometimes get right result and sometimes get wrong result.And without those __synthreads(), the result may be more difficult to fine the problem,I think.

Comment: Isn't the mismatch because of same numbers having different indices?

Comment: yes, the max value is correct in both CPU and GPU result, but index in GPU and CPU sometimes mismatch

Comment: I know the what causes this problem and finally figure out other way instead use __synthread, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @skycastle0814 If you have solved your problem you could post an answer and lately accept it. This will remove this answer from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another loop to deal with the index to avoid same max value with different index problem in this computation

```
int temp=0;
for(i=0;i<tbp;i++)
{ 
    if(d[blockIdx.x]==a[i] && temp==0)
    {temp = i;}
} 
idx[0] = temp;
```

Answer (score -1):

you need set int temp= -1 instead 0 to avoid the case of maximum value lcoated  at 0.

Comment: Post it as a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31905893)